# Endless loop and a break for TUI in Haskell

Tags: haskell, terminal, tui

I want to listen for keypresses and depending on those, use commands from System.Console.ANSI

package to manipulate console interface for my program.

In Python I would to this

```
while True:
    read_from_console()
    if condition:
        print_stuff_into_console
        break
```

How do I approach such task in Haskell, in simplest possible way?
Thanks

Comment: Use the Brick library - it gives you really useful widgets and abstractions for TUIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent abstract pseudo-ish code in Haskell would look like:

```
loop = do
    line <- readFromConsole
    if condition line
        then do
            printStuffToConsole
            loop  -- Recurse - i.e. repeat the same thing again
        else 
            pure ()  -- Don't recurse - the function execution ends

 main = loop
```

But of course the devil would be in how `readFromConsole` and `printStuffToConsole` look. And these really depend on what exactly you'd like to do.

I will offer the dumbest possible implementation, just to illustrate how everything works and to build a complete program.

Let's say that "read from console" just means having the user enter a line of text and press Enter. For that, you can use [the `getLine` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.20/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#v:getLine):

```
readFromConsole = getLine
```

And let's say you want to print the same thing every time. For printing, you can use [the `putStrLn` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.20/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn):

```
printStuffToConsole = putStrLn "Give me another!"
```

And then let's say that the condition for stopping is that the user enters "STOP". This can be expressed with a string comparison:

```
condition line = line /= "STOP"
```

If you put all of that together, you get a complete program:

```
loop = do
    line <- readFromConsole
    if condition line
        then do
            printStuffToConsole
            loop  -- Recurse - i.e. repeat the same thing again
        else 
            pure ()  -- Don't recurse - the function execution ends

    where
        readFromConsole = getLine
        printStuffToConsole = putStrLn "Give me another!"
        condition line = line /= "STOP"

 main = loop
```

Of course, while it's nice to have parts of the program semantically named, you don't strictly speaking have to do it if you wanted to make the whole thing shorter:

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    if line /= "STOP"
        then do
            putStrLn "Give me another!"
            main
        else 
            pure ()
```

Comment: Great answer. Idiomatically, it's typical to use `when p act` instead of `if p then act else pure ()`.

Comment: Good point @DanielWagner. I was just trying to avoid having to explain what `when` is, and how it's different from `if`, etc. Better to start from first principles and develop from there.

Answer (score 2):

Fyodor Soikin already provided the simple way to do it.

Here I'll comment on a general way to "break" a loop: using continuations and `callCC`.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "start"
  flip runContT return $ callCC $ \break -> forever $ do
    l <- lift $ getLine
    if l == "quit"
      then break ()
      else lift $ putStrLn $ "not a quit command " ++ l
    lift $ putStrLn "next iteration"
  putStrLn "end"
```

Continuations are infamously hard to grasp, but the above code is not too complex. A rough intuition is as follows.

The `forever` library function is used to repeat an action indefinitely, it is the Haskell equivalent of `while true`.

The `flip runContT return $ callCC $ \f -> ....` part means "define `f` to be a break-like function, which will exit the "block" `....` immediately. In the code, I call that `break` to make that clear. The call `break ()` interrupts the `forever` (and returns the `()` outside -- we could use that value if we wrote `x <- flip runContT ....` to bind it to `x`).

There is a downside, though. In the `....` part we no longer work inside the `IO` monad, but in the `ContT () IO` monad. That is what lets us call `break ()`. In order to use regular `IO` there, we need to `lift` the `IO` actions. So, we can't use `putStrLn ".."` but we need to use `lift $ putStrLn ".."` instead.

The rest should be more or less straightforward to follow.

Here's a small demo in GHCi.

```
> main
start
1 (typed by the user)
not a quit command 1
next iteration
2 (typed by the user)
not a quit command 2
next iteration
3 (typed by the user)
not a quit command 3
next iteration
4 (typed by the user)
not a quit command 4
next iteration
quit (typed by the user)
end
```

Is it a good idea to use continuation just for `break`? Maybe. If you are not familiar with this technique, probably it is not worth it. The plain recursive approach looks much simpler.